# Code not running - C++ - exam training tests

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have this very exercise which requires me to use a function named **shift**, which gets two parameters, one named **n**, number of items, and an array **x**, maximum 100 elements, therefor this function moves the array's items one by one. Then I need to inverse the array calling this function. I don't get why my code doesn't work. What should I do?

```
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void shift(int n, int x[]) {
    int aux1 = x[1], aux = x[n - 1];
    x[n - 1] = x[n];
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 2; i--) {
        int t = x[i - 1];
        x[i - 1] = aux;
        aux = t;
    }
    x[n] = aux1;
}

int main(){
    int n, x[100], v[100], rez[100]; cin >> n;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> x[i];
        v[i] = x[i];
    }
    int t = n, k = 1, j = 0, pos = 0;
    while (t !=  0) {
        k = 1, pos = 0;
        while (k != 0) {
            while (v[1] != x[t]&&pos==t) {
                shift(n, v);
                pos++;
            }
            k = 1;
        }
        j++;
        rez[j] = x[t];
        t--;
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        cout << rez[i] << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {` Array indices are zero based. This will access the arrays out of bounds if `n == 100` and not set the first element at all. You should also `#include <iostream>` since you're using it.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to copy #include <iostream>
regarding the indices, i start with 1 and go all the way to n, not from 0 to < n, all the elements are read in the array and it's the same thing

Comment: It is not the same thing when you access the arrays out of bounds because of it. You should edit your question to include the correct header as well as provide a sample of input, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: @Alex "_i start with 1 and go all the way to n, not from 0 to < n, all the elements are read in the array and it's the same thing_" Accessing `n`'th element of an array is accessing the array out of bounds. Doing so invokes undefined behavior, which might result in "code not running". Due to this fact, it's not the same thing, as not accessing array out of bounds.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius i got it now, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shift sounds like a primitive rotate, so let's implement that

```
void shift (int arr[], int elements){
    int holder = arr[0];
    for(int i = 0; i != elements-1; i++){
        arr[i] = arr[i+1];
    }
    arr[elements - 1] = holder;
}
```

If you take the numbers {1,2,3} and run them through, you should have either {3,1,2} or {2,3,1}, it doesn't really matter in the end, because now you have one number in the correct place. So let's keep going!

```
void reverse(int arr[], int elements){
    for(auto i = elements;i>0;i--){
        shift(arr, i);
    };
}
```

Since you only need to get the remaining numbers in place, you may as well create a separate function for that

```
int main(){
    int num[] = {1,2,3};
    for (auto i: num){
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
    reverse(num, 3);
    for (auto i: num){
        std::cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

Finally put it all together

Comment: hah, sounds pretty logic to me now. i had a very bad idea like creating 1 separate array, counting the positions of the rotations and then adding the numbers to one final array which i could display. it is very inefficient, thanks for this solution!

Comment: You should be aware that this method for reversing is very slow, but it fulfills the task. This performs in O(N^2) time, better reverse algorithms can be done in O(N).